# How to debug why collection_select isn't working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to **collection_select**. I have watched a couple of Youtube videos and read the information about collection_select on RailsGuides and searched on Stack Overflow. But I am having a difficult time understanding what data goes where and a collection_select works.

This is causing me to write my own collection_select wrong. What information goes where, and also what information should go in my own collection_select?

I'm currently building a lightweight CRM and trying to assign a `:contact_id` to a deal, but when I try to do this I keep getting an error which I have provided a screenshot below. The error states:

> 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
>
> - contact must exist

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcGnt.png)

Here is my **deals_controller.rb** file:

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController

def index
@deals = Deal.all
end

def new
@deal = Deal.new
end

def show
@deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
end

def create
@deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
if @deal.save
redirect_to organization_contact_deal_url(@deal)
else
render :new
end
end

private
def deal_params
params.require(:deal).permit(:deal_name, :deal_amount, :contact_id)
end

end
```

Here is my **new.html.erb** file for deals:

```
 <%= form_with scope: :deal, url: organization_contact_deals_path, local: true do |form| %>
 <% if @deal.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
 <h2><%= pluralize(@deal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved: </h2>

  <ul>
  <% @deal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
  <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
  <%= form.label :deal_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :deal_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= form.label :contact_id %>

  <%= form.collection_select(:contact_id, Contact.all, :id, :full_name) %>

 </p>

 <p>
 <%= form.submit %>
 </p>

 <% end %>
```

Here is my **schema.rb**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171209203509) do

create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "contact_first_name"
t.string "contact_last_name"
t.integer "organization_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["organization_id"], name: 
"index_contacts_on_organization_id"
end

create_table "deals", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "deal_name"
t.string "deal_amount"
t.integer "contact_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_deals_on_contact_id"
end

create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "organization_name"
t.string "organization_industry"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

end
```

Here is my **deal.rb** model file:

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :contact
end
```

Here is my **contact.rb** model file:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :organization
has_many :deals, dependent: :destroy

def full_name
"#{contact_first_name} #{contact_last_name}"
end
end
```

Here are my **routes**:

```
                        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                   Controller#Action
         welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                      
         welcome#index
         organization_contact_deals GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals(.:format)          deals#index
                       POST   /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals(.:format)          deals#create
         new_organization_contact_deal GET /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/new(.:format)      deals#new
         edit_organization_contact_deal GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/:id/edit(.:format) deals#edit
         organization_contact_deal GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/:id(.:format)      deals#show
                       PATCH  /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/:id(.:format)      deals#update
                       PUT    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/:id(.:format)      deals#update
                       DELETE /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:contact_id/deals/:id(.:format)      deals#destroy
        organization_contacts GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts(.:format)                            contacts#index
                       POST   /organizations/:organization_id/contacts(.:format)                            contacts#create
        new_organization_contact GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/new(.:format)                        contacts#new
        edit_organization_contact GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:id/edit(.:format)                   contacts#edit
        organization_contact GET    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:id(.:format)                        contacts#show
                       PATCH  /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:id(.:format)                        contacts#update
                       PUT    /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:id(.:format)                        contacts#update
                       DELETE /organizations/:organization_id/contacts/:id(.:format)                        contacts#destroy
         organizations GET    /organizations(.:format)                                                      organizations#index
                       POST   /organizations(.:format)                                                      organizations#create
        new_organization GET    /organizations/new(.:format)                                                  organizations#new
        edit_organization GET    /organizations/:id/edit(.:format)                                             organizations#edit
         organization GET    /organizations/:id(.:format)                                                  organizations#show
                       PATCH  /organizations/:id(.:format)                                                  organizations#update
                       PUT    /organizations/:id(.:format)                                                  organizations#update
                       DELETE /organizations/:id(.:format)                                                  organizations#destroy
                  root GET    /
```

Here is my **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'welcome/index'

resources :organizations do
resources :contacts do
resources :deals
end
end

root 'welcome#index'
end
```

**Edit**:

I updated my contact.rb file, new.html.erb form and deals_controller.rb. I will leave a much more detailed edit log once this problum is fixed.

**New Error After Changed:**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in DealsController#create

No route matches {:action=>"show", :contact_id=>"2", 
:controller=>"deals", :organization_id=>#<Deal id: 6, deal_name: 
"Office365 deal", deal_amount: nil, contact_id: 2, created_at: "2017-
12-10 03:35:48", updated_at: "2017-12-10 03:35:48">}, missing 
required keys: [:id]

@deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
if @deal.save
**redirect_to organization_contact_deal_url(@deal)**
else
render :new
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `:contact_id` from your allowed parameters:

```
def deal_params
  params.require(:deal).permit(:deal_name, :deal_amount, :contact_id)
end
```

Add a `full_name` instance method to your *Contact* model

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :deals, dependent: :destroy

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

In your form:

```
<%= form.collection_select :contact_id, Contact.all, :id, :full_name %>
```

In your controller *create* action:

```
 def create
   @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
   if @deal.save
     redirect_to @deal
   else
     render :new
   end
 end
```

Comment: I tried this and i'm still getting the same error :/

Comment: Update my answer, replace `:contact_first_name` and `:contact_last_name` from your `collection_select_tag`. Use a instance method on your Contact model.

Comment: Alright, I changed my collection_select to look like this: `<%= form.collection_select(:contact_id, Contact.all, :id, :contact_last_name) %>`. So the params was one of the issues and it's capturing the ID. But now there is a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in DealsController#create` error. You can find this under my deals_controller.rb on line #18. It's this: `redirect_to organization_contact_deal_url(@deal)`. If you want me to make an edit to my question I will so it's easier to read.

Comment: Ok... could you update your question and place the contents of your `routes.rb` file please

Comment: Okay, I updated my question and placed my routes.rb there.

Comment: Replace `organization_contact_deal_url(@deal)` for just @deal. See my updated answer

Comment: Hmm... now it's giving me a `NoMethodError in DealsController#create` `undefined method 'deal_url' for #<DealsController:0x007fb62bcf0970>` error

Comment: My mistake. I don't realize that is a nested route. Replace `resources :deals` with `resources :deals, shallow: true`

Comment: Sorry I was updating my last error when you wrote your last comment. There is currently still an error after I submit the form. By the way, the form is working and is displaying the data on my screen. Just not redirecting me after it's submitted. Anyways, the error is `ActionController::ActionControllerError in DealsController#create
` and `Cannot redirect to nil!`. It's on the same line as before.

Comment: What does `Cannot redirect to nil!` mean exactly? I have had this error in the past but wasn't sure what was going on.

Comment: I'm guessing is because you haven't set `Contact`. Try to add another resource `resources :deals` at the bottom of your `routes.rb` file just above `root 'welcome#index'`. Let me Know...

Comment: Alright, so I changed my `deals_controller.rb` create section to `redirect_to organization_contact_deals_path(@deal)` and now everything is working so far :). Thank you so much for your help seriously. I can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: Great! Glad to help... by the way it is not recommended resources should not be more than one level deep. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html section 2.7.1 for more information